# Context.clearRect in Canvas doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage

If I get a picture and want to draw it to move to the right side, it works.  But when I add `clearRect()`, the picture disappears. How can I use similar code with the right method so that `clearRect()` will work?

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#canvas_id{
border:1px solid red;
 }
 </style>
 </head>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas_id"></canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById( "canvas_id" );
var Context = canvas.getContext( "2d" );
var x1 = 10;
var x2 = 10;

var img = new Image();
img.src = "example.jpg";
img.onload = function(){ Context.drawImage( img, x1, x2,20,20); }

draw();

function draw(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

 Context.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);

 var Img = new Image();
 Img.src = "example.jpg";
 Img.onload = function(){ Context.drawImage( Img, x1, x2,20,20); }


 x1 = x1 +1;


}
</script>
</body>
```

If I take a rectangle with `fillRect()` instead of an image, the code works.

Comment: Why do you want to add clearRect()? What are you trying  to achieve?

Comment: The image is going to recreated everytime in a one more position and if i dont use something like clearRect(), the old positions don't clear, so the animation looks bad and wrong :/   I just want to transform an image to the right with canvas .

Comment: Because i'll need canvas later for some other things dont be important for this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Load your image only once.

- Loading an image is always asynchronous, even when cached.
- `requestAnimationFrame` callback will be called just **before** the next paint to screen.

Here is a schematic view of what happens in your code:

```
clearRect start_to_load_Img || ... img.loaded=>drawImage ... clearRect start_to_load_Img || etc.
                            ^                                                            ^
               render new frame to screen                                    render new frame to screen
```

As you can see, every time your image loads in between two frames. But just before the next frame is passed to screen, you would have cleared it.

So a fixed code would look like

```
// load your image only once
var img = new Image();
img.src = "example.jpg";

draw();

function draw(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  Context.clearRect(0,0,innerWidth,innerHeight);
  if(img.naturalWidth) { // check it has loaded
    Context.drawImage(img, x1, x2,20,20);
  }
 ...
```